# mysql query repeats results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query. I need to select the rows if logo is empty OR button is empty OR vanitylogo is empty. This seems to be working but, printing multiple rows for same mid. How to fix this ?

```
SELECT fmm.mid,
       fmm.name ,
       fmn.mnname,
       fmm.button,
       fmm.logo,
       fmm.vanitylogo
FROM X fmm ,
     Y fmn
WHERE fmm.`button` = ''
  OR fmm.`button` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`button` = 'None'
  OR fmm.`logo` = ''
  OR fmm.`logo` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`logo` = 'None'
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` = ''
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` IS NULL
  AND fmm.mid=fmn.nid
  AND fmm.status='active'
  AND fmm.xyz_status='active'
```

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you take a look at this webpage http://flylib.com/books/en/2.823.1.194/1/ Code Complete 2, "examples of psychological distances between variable names"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got two major problems with your query:

1. You have not correctly bracketed your `OR` conditions
2. You have no join condition between the tables, leading to a "cross join"

Try this:

```
SELECT fmm.mid,
       fmm.name ,
       fmn.mnname,
       fmm.button,
       fmm.logo,
       fmm.vanitylogo
FROM X fmm
JOIN Y fmn ON fmn.some_column = X.some_column -- FIX THIS
WHERE (fmm.`button` in ('', 'NULL', 'None')
  OR fmm.`logo` IN ('', 'NULL', 'None')
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` IN ('', 'NULL')
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` IS NULL)
  AND fmm.mid=fmn.nid
  AND fmm.status='active'
  AND fmm.xyz_status='active'
```

You must fill in the "FIX THIS": line with the appropriate column names

Regarding the ORs, I bundled some up into IN() condition, and bracketed up the lot.

Comment: but this is selecting results , in which vanitylogo is NULL and not selecting the other rows in which the other columns are NULL

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the table 'Y fmn'. For every row in Y, the results will be repeated.  You need a way to aggregate the results, possibly with a group by.

```
SELECT fmm.mid,
       fmm.name ,
       fmn.mnname,
       fmm.button,
       fmm.logo,
       fmm.vanitylogo
FROM X fmm ,
     Y fmn
WHERE fmm.`button` = ''
  OR fmm.`button` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`button` = 'None'
  OR fmm.`logo` = ''
  OR fmm.`logo` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`logo` = 'None'
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` = ''
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` = 'NULL'
  OR fmm.`vanitylogo` IS NULL
  AND fmm.mid=fmn.nid
  AND fmm.status='active'
  AND fmm.xyz_status='active'
group by fmm.mid,
       fmm.name ,
       fmn.mnname,
       fmm.button,
       fmm.logo,
       fmm.vanitylogo
```